# Parse links from WebBrowser if source code is not updated

Tags: c#, browser

It should be such a problem: I should parse links from the site. Everything would be fine, but the links are displayed in the script and in the source code they are not. More precisely, they are, but the old ones.

Here is the site: http://54.join.ru/resume?q=

Need to parse links to resume. Everything is fine. But when you go to some other page, for example 5, a summary of changes, and the source code are old links, ie those that were on the first page.

Can anybody suggest how can I parse the new links? Write in c # using webBrowser.

Comment: Do you mean `Parse` instead of `Spars`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp).

> Selenium-WebDriver was developed to better support dynamic web pages
>   where elements of a page may change without the page itself being
>   reloaded.

Thus you will be able to access elements on a web page that has been changed dynamically by javascript.

---

Following code for example finds an element by given class name:

```
IWebElement we =  driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ra-elements-list__new-window-link"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you suggest how to get links that have class = ra-elements-list__new-window-link using Selenium WebDriver