# How to click buttons/links which are in iframe? (GeckoFx)

Tags: c#, geckofx

This code access iframe and gets me source code.

```
string content = null;
var iframe = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe").FirstOrDefault() as Gecko.DOM.GeckoIFrameElement;
if (iframe != null)
{
    var html = iframe.ContentDocument.DocumentElement as GeckoHtmlElement;
    if (html != null)
        content = html.OuterHtml;

    textBox1.Text = content;
}
```

I tried puting some code

```
string content = null;
var iframe = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe").FirstOrDefault() as Gecko.DOM.GeckoIFrameElement;
if (iframe != null)
{
    var html = iframe.ContentDocument.DocumentElement as GeckoHtmlElement;
    if (html != null)
        content = html.OuterHtml;

    textBox1.Text = content;

    GeckoElementCollection elements = browser.Document.GetElementsByName("username");
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        GeckoInputElement input = (GeckoInputElement)element;
        input.Value = "Auto filled!";
    }
}
```

But it wont work as code dont find elements. Any ideas?

Tried searching google for any iframe examples but seems that there isnt any good documentation for it.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25854559/2224701

Comment: I know selenium webdriver and I tried but I need to work with firefox browser (geckoFx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you looking for in the main document? You should look for in a frame.

```
string content = null;
var iframe = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe").FirstOrDefault() as Gecko.DOM.GeckoIFrameElement;
if (iframe != null)
{
    var html = iframe.ContentDocument.DocumentElement as GeckoHtmlElement;
    if (html != null)
        content = html.OuterHtml;

    textBox1.Text = content;

    GeckoElementCollection elements = iframe.ContentDocument.GetElementsByName("username");
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        GeckoInputElement input = (GeckoInputElement)element;
        input.Value = "Auto filled!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, "browser.Document" is main document. "iframe.ContentDocument" iframe doc. Thanks for help!